# how to get data usage(cellular or wifi)breakdown of other applications used, from my application

Tags: iphone

I want to know exactly data usage of my native email application from my application which will be running in the background.I am able to get full data usage of iphone but not getting the breakdown usage ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API available for this information. Apple do not provide application's access to it. As of iOS 7, you can see a breakdown of cellular data consumed on a per app basis in the System app.

Apps that claim to provide data usage statistics do it in one of two ways. They have the user run *everything* through a proxy server (bad), or they use a unix utility that's rather inaccurate because it resets on system reboot (I'm simplifying quite a bit here).

Basically, there's no supported method to do this. Any app that *does* claim to do it is using a half-arsed implementation that isn't particularly accurate, *or* has substantial privacy concerns. If you just need to know cellular data consumption for your own reference you can use the System app on iOS 7.

Comment: Am building an app for people with OCD. I want to fetch native email data traffic particularly in my application to arrive at a pattern using which we can predict their behavior under OCD attack. Can we use any C libraries?? Found some results using netstat..

Comment: I alluded to this in my answer, but the problem is the counters you're accessing get reset on every reboot. You can *somewhat* get around this by registering as an app that gets launched on startup (ie, a VOIP app), but this isn't strictly kosher with regards to the app store. You may find this is 'good enough' for you though...it depends how accurate you want to be.